# Android - Prevent MultiChoice dialog item click

Tags: android

I have the following dialog :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(itemsArray, selectionArray, this);
builder.setPositiveButton("Valider", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

I want the **cancel** some items click. Like when the user click on an items, I want to somehow `return false` and ignore the click.
Any ideas ?

Comment: use a flag with array, if flag return false

Comment: The return type of `onClick` is void

Comment: i am just telling a sample, use your  logic  by making any global variable or another function with return type or what ever you want